# In SQL Server, how can I insert values into table EXCEPT repeat rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a python script which would look at a text file and create SQL code which would insert data into a table.

It looked like this:

```
insert into table1 (date, locid, personid, itemid, amounts) 
   values (val11,val12,val13,val14,val15)
         ,(val21,val22,val23,val24,val25)
```

The data is structured so that for a particular set of values the first four columns `(date, locid, personid, itemid)`, there will be at most one row.

At the moment, I have to check by hand if an entry already exists in the table, then remove it from the insert statement.

How can I enter this data into the DB without manually checking for repeats?

Comment: What happens if you have two rows that just differ with two amounts - which amount should end up in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Create a second table, table2, with the DDL for just the columns involved in your insert.

Do your inserts into table2.

Then run:

```
insert into table1 (date, locid, personid, itemid, amounts)
select t2.* from table2 t2
join(
select locid, personid, itemid, amounts from table2
  except
   select locid, personid, itemid, amounts from table1) x
   on t2.locid = x.locid
  and t2.personid = x.personid
  and t2.itemid = x.itemid
  and t2.amounts = x.amounts
```

Then you can delete table2.

And table1 will be populated with only those INSERTS where values in all 4 columns are not a match with all 4 columns on any existing row of table1.

This assumes you do not want the INSERT to go through only if there exists a match in all 4 columns. In other words the above will do the INSERT if there is a row where 3 of the 4 columns match. It only stops the INSERT when there already exists a row that is a perfect match on all 4 columns.

If you have duplicate INSERT statements being generated as well, simply add the DISTINCT operator to the query, "select DISTINCT t2.* from table2 t2"

As ludwigmace pointed out in the comments maybe try the following as well and compare the performance difference, it should be functionally equivalent (if the inserts don't contain duplicates, you can get rid of the group by) ---

```
insert into table1 (date, locid, personid, itemid, amounts)
SELECT t2.date, t2.locid, t2.personid, t2.itemid, t2.amounts
  FROM table2 t2
  LEFT JOIN t1
    ON t2.date = t1.date
   AND t2.locid = t1.locid
   AND t2.personid = t1.personid
   AND t2.itemid = t1.itemid
 WHERE t1.date is null
 GROUP BY t2.date, t2.locid, t2.personid, t2.itemid, t2.amounts
```

Comment: That checks all columns whilst only the first 4 should be checked

Comment: @Mark I misread what he said and thought he had multiple indentical inserts and wanted to make the inserts unique. I just changed my answer. It will insert into table1 all of the inserts that would not result in a duplicate of the values in those 4 columns.

Comment: This won't give the desired results if `table2` contains duplicate rows that don't yet exist in `t1`. (I didn't vote, not that that should matter.)

Comment: If you're saying that his inserts might contain duplicates themselves then I agree, but it doesn't look like that is a problem he is having. The question states he wants to check for 'duplicates' as in the rows already exist in table1 (not that there are duplicate insert statements being generated). If that is the case, however, all he has to do is add one word, DISTINCT

Comment: I like to do that - get data into the DB first and then massage into my table.  I don't know how SQL optimizes those 3 select statements, though, so I'd go with:
`SELECT t2.date, t2.locid, t2.personid, t2.itemid, t2.amounts
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t2.date = t1.date AND t2.locid = t1.locid AND t2.personid = t1.personid AND t2.itemid = t1.itemid
WHERE t1.date is null
GROUP BY t2.date, t2.locid, t2.personid, t2.itemid, t2.amounts`

Comment: Ideally he could do without the distinct, yeah. There are several options if the inserts also contain duplicates. Doing some deletes from t2 (for duplicates within itself and for duplicates with t1) could result in a simple 1 line select like that, for the insert

Comment: Commented before I saw your whole thing there, I like it, not sure how much differently the execution plan would be in sql server though. I don't think you need the group by though? or are you doing that to supress duplicates?

Comment: Yep, just to suppress duplicates; probably executed by MSSQL the same as DISTINCT.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
    INSERT INTO [table1] ([date], [locid], [personid], [itemid], [amounts])
    SELECT val1, val2, val3, val4, val5
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
       SELECT * FROM [table1] WHERE [date]=val1 AND [locid]=val2 AND [personid]=val3 AND [itemid]=val4
    )
```

Instead of inserting values directly, you insert from the result of a select statement.
The select statement is crafted to only return the values that you specify if they don't already exist

You can control the scope of uniqueness (the combination of which columns should be unique) by modifying the Where-clause in the second select (i.e. add or remove comparisons as needed)

Comment: Instead of a single insert statement with multiple rows of data added, with this the OP's code would execute a slew of insert statements, one for each row.  Seems kinda heavy.